# LATEX Increase Horizontal Tabular Space

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section*{TEST}
\begin{tabular}{L!{}R}
Time&{Date}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The lines above make:

[image]

How I can increase/customise the distance between 'Time' and 'Date' leaving everything the same?

Comment: There are not L, or R columns in standard tabular. Moreover,  `!{}` need thr array package. Besides this, try `\setlength\tabcolsep{3cm}
\begin{tabular}{lr} Time&{Date}\ \end{tabular}`. This solves the question?

Comment: @Fran thanks so much. Is there a way to specify spacing on the left and the middle? So that I can customize how much white space before 'Time' and between 'Time' and 'Date'? Your advice works great but applies 3cm to all gaps

Comment: `\tabcolsep` apply equally to each column border, so the outer spaces are the half of the space between cells. If you need different spaces you can use `@{...}`     where `...` could be any horizontal space as `\quad`, `\hspace{1em}`, `~~~`, etc. For instance, try some like `\begin{tabular}{@{\qquad}l@{\ \ \ \ \ }r@{\hspace{5cm}}}`